# Concurrent session control in aws cognito using custom attribute

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, amazon-cognito

I want to use a custom attribute as a counter in aws cognito and increase the counter for every successful login of the same user for a maximum concurrent sessions of 3. When the concurrent user sessions reach 3, i should be able to block any further login attempts from the same user. I am using aws cognito as the authentication and authorization server with java, spring for server side. Or Is there any better way to implement the maximum concurrent sessions(3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cognito isn't designed for this and you are definitely going to run into trouble along the way. the stateless auth that cognito provides, by its nature isn't a session. You could use an endpoint `GET /session` where you provide the access token and it returns a session token. In that handler do whatever checks you want.

Comment: You would generate a session token, store it in dynamodb with a user id, timestamp and a TTL. Then in your authorization layer check the table to see if session token is in the 3 latest session tokens for a given user id. That's the simplest example but obviously features and additional controls add complexity.